# Spring Boot. ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar "RUN AS" "MAVEN INSTALL" pero, en vez de localmente, en un servidor remoto?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Tengo un problema. En mi empresa existe un proyecto que, dado un WSDL, te genera unas clases (son clases que se necesitan para hacer llamadas SOAP).

Habitualmente suelo usar Spring Tool Suite y al poder usar ese proyecto, para obtener las clases que necesito, tengo que pulsar con el botón derecho "RUN AS", escojo "MAVEN INSTALL" y entonces se generan varios .java que necesitaré incorporar a otro proyecto.

El problema es que ahora necesito hacer eso pero no desde mi equipo (en local) si no desde un servidor remoto que tiene Linux instalado. Es decir, en vez de ejecutarlo desde mi equipo, que era lo que venía haciendo hasta ahora, tengo que encontrar la forma de ejecutarlo desde ese server que sí tiene acceso a urls del WSDL, solo así conseguiré que se generen las clases .java que voy a necesitar (en local no funciona porque desde mi máquina no tengo acceso a la url del WSDL).

¿Alguien sabe si es posible hacer algo así? Sería hacer "RUN AS", "MAVEN INSTALL", pero en vez de en local, desde otro servidor (al que tendré que subir el proyecto completo, imagino).

Comment: Eso lo que está haciendo es correr la fase Install de la configuración Maven en el proyecto. Cambiando esa configuración (el pom.xml), cambia la forma como se ejecuta. Esa fase instala en el repositorio Maven local. Posiblemente lo qe necesitas es hacer mvn deploy https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente tuve que subir el proyecto completo al servidor, desde allí hice "mvn install". Tuve que instalar maven y también jdk y después de eso ya funcionó el "mvn install" exactamente igual que me funcionaba en local.